# Is there a way to add Google mail in a database and use it with Next-Auth's Google provider?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I'm building a multi tenant app in which a tenant can add multiple users that will have access to the tenant app.

Currently I'm using Next-Auth credentials provider but I'm thnking about switching over to Google provider to have a better user experience and developer experience.

The problem is that, in my app, the tenant creates a user by entering a name and a mail so, if I switch to Google, I'll just have to enter the mail corresponding to the Google account. I tried it and this method does not work (it says that I'm not using the corresponding provider).

I need to make it work like that because I don't want a user not assigned to a tenant to access my app.

How can I make the Google provider works by simply entering the mail ? Is ot even possible ? If not what is the alternative ?